# [fixed]Trigger an ajax Submit Form button by clicking on a div

Tags: forms, javascript, ajax

I've a form inside a custom template and I would like to trigger the submit button clicking on one div. Then the function submitForm sends the form-data to a webservices using Drupal httpClient.

The twig template is like:

```
<div class="Rectangle" id="rectangle-div" >
 This is the div containing some stuff that I want to click to submit the form.
</div>

<form id="form-id">
{{ form.elem }}
{{ form.actions.submit }}
</form>
```

I tried with a simple jQuery function like:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#rectangle-div').on('click', function () {
            var wrapper = $('#form-id');
            $('.form-submit', wrapper).trigger( "click" );
        });
    });
});
```

I tried also to write a selector like:

```
$('button[id^="edit-mod-submit"]', wrapper).trigger( "click");
```

if I try with a simple submit like

```
$('form-id').submit();
```

the js code submits the form but refresh the page avoiding ajax and furthermore doesn't send data to the WS:

(if I use the submit button the data goes to the WS).

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE #1: FIXED**

I added inside the ajax option of my submit button the event 'click' and now, using jQuery, I am able to send the post request to the WS. The form is like:

```
 $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
            '#button_type' => 'primary',
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => '::setMessage',
                'event' => 'click',
            ],

        );
```

The jQuery function is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        var wrapper = $('#form-id');
        $('.form-submit', wrapper).trigger( "click" );
    });
```

Now I should intercept the response coming from the webserver and then execute a JS script, but these are other questions :)

Comment: Is this copied and pasted from your code? The `<div class="Rectangle id="rectangle-div" >` is missing a " after Rectangle which would cause the rest of the code to not work correctly

Comment: @ColinShipton it is not the original code, but I corrected the error.

Comment: Why not add your "fixed" as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not triggering an AJAX call, it will just submit the form normally via JavaScript rather than pressing a button, etc. If you want submit the form via AJAX you will need something like:

```
  var url = $('#form-id').attr('action');
  $.getJSON(url, {
    field1: 'data1',
    field2: 'data2'
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Place this inside `$('#rectangle-div').on('click', function () {`

Comment: Ok I tried this piece of code but it cannot enter inside the done(function) and the ws doesn't receive any post request. Furthermore: why do I use Key,Value pairs inside the function if I use the form to send data to the webservice?

Comment: You need to use key/value pairs as you're not submitting the form, you're replacing the submit with an AJAX call, etc. can you post the whole code rather than just snippets?

Comment: Also, the getJSON function also has a .fail (i.e. `.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {`

Comment: the error is "parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data".
The original code is very similar, but it contains more data. In any case now I can contact the webserver using jQuery, but I'm not able to receive the response. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: Sounds to me as if the webservice is not returning JSON